# Meaning of these sentence

Tags: meaning

"did you heard me having said you that?"

Is the sentence imply same meaning as

"did you hear me that i had said you that?"
Moreover when we can use "did you hear me say"
Because we use gerund or infinitive after ' hear'

Comment: What is the source of the first quote.  It is ungrammatical to say "did you heard..."

Comment: The sentence is very ungrammatical and therefore meaningless. It's bad enough that it's not clear how it should be fixed, unless you can explain the intended meaning.

Comment: If people heard me saying something to someone